# File and Printer Sharing, in 10.0.0.x

Tags: networking, windows-xp, printer, file-sharing

I have a strange problem:

When I assign addresses of the form 10.0.0.x to my computers, file sharing (smb) does not work.

When I assign them addresse of the form 192.168.1.x it works...

OS is XP SP3, for subnetmasks i tried both 255.255.255.0 and 255.0.0.0

Any ideas what I can do?

[EDIT]
I forgot to add: pinging doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Is your router's IP address set to 10.0.0.1? If it's set to 192.168.1.1, this might not work.

Comment: The routers ip address is 10.0.0.138.

The PCs are assigned adresses by DHCP.


But even when I disconnect the router and set the addresses manually it doesn't work

Comment: If you disconnect your router, you don't have a network.

Answer (score 0):

Don't configure IP adresses manually!  Install [Bonjour for Windows](http://support.apple.com/downloads/Bonjour_for_Windows) and have it find everything automatically.